# Using "this" keyword on object members on initialization

Tags: c#, this

I got a delegate for OnBuy and OnSell of my items objects, the problem is I'm going to copy paste some of items and not modify the keyword name for each OnBuy and OnSell and try to use "this" keyword, I've added my function to the item class, but still can't access it without modifying the object name after copy paste. Here's my codes:

```
        public static Item item = new Item
        {
            Name = "Item",
            ID = 1,
            Price = 50,
            Info = "Awesome!",
            OnBuy = delegate(Client cli)
            {
                // Invalid
                this.BuyTitle(cli);

                // Still can't change
                this.Name = "AAA";

                return true;
            },
            OnSell = delegate(Client cli)
            {
                // Invalid
                this.SellTitle(cli);

                // Still can't change
                this.Name = "AAA";

                return true;
            }
         }
```

And here's the item class:

```
    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int Price { get; set; }

        public string Info { get; set; }

        public Func<Client, bool> OnBuy { get; set; }

        public Func<Client, bool> OnSell { get; set; }

        public bool BuyTitle(Client cli)
        {
            ...
        }

        public bool SellTitle(Client cli)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code makes my eyes hurt. Why are you using a delegate in this situation?

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk Because I have a background system that has many items and sends some events once somebody is buying items, for example sending no money message or stuffs like that.

Comment: Read some basic book on OOP/OOD please.

Comment: @vittore I got what you mean already, But I'm looking for a way to detect value/object by using a keyword that is same on all items.

Comment: Always list the exact error. I'm guessing that `this` is not defined at that point (because the initialization is static).

Comment: I think you might want to use [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx) here. You should usually pass the sender as a parameter, so you can access the raising item's properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using object initializer syntax to create an instance of `Item`. It is not possible for the anonymous delegate to use `this` because it is not possible to for an object initializer to reference the object it is creating. From section 7.6.10.2 of the C# spec:

> It is not possible for the object initializer to refer to the newly created object it is initializing.

I'm not sure that delegates are the most appropriate mechanism here, but if you still want to use them, I would create a static method which creates the item and call that to initialize the static field.

Here is an outline of what you can do:

```
public static Item item = CreateItem();

private static Item CreateItem()
{
    var item = new Item() { Name = "Item" };
    item.OnBuy = client => { item.OnBuy(client); item.Name = "AAA" };
    return item;
}
```